# countdown timer is overlapping in python

Tags: python, tkinter, timer, countdown

I am doing a project about Trivia.
I made a countdown timer that works kinda good but every time that I go to the next slide the timer is overlapping with the previous one.
Even though I reset the timer it's for some reason doesn't.
Here is the full code if needed (most relevant stuff in lines 215-450):

```
from tkinter import *
import operator

def Home():

        def name():
                name = entry_name.get()
                welcome_label = Label(
                        window,
                        text="Hello " + name + " you may start your trivia game by clicking at the 'Start' button" ,
                        bg = "#93b4ba",
                        fg="#4287f5",
                        font=("Jomhuria",35,"bold"))
                welcome_label.place(x=0,y=250)
                

        def instructions_Window():
                instructions_Window = Toplevel()
                instructions_Window.title("instructions")

                instructions = Label(
                        instructions_Window,
                        text = "WELCOME TO THE TRIVIA GAME!\nYour will answer 10 question, the questions will be about general knowledge.\nMake sure you are doing your best maybe you will on the leaderboard soon!\n GOOD LUCK!!!",
                        font = ("Staatliches",30))
                instructions.pack()

                back_but = Button(
                        instructions_Window,
                        text="Back",
                        command=instructions_Window.destroy)
                back_but.pack()

        def clear():
                for widgets in window.winfo_children():
                        widgets.destroy()

        clear()
        window.config(bg="#93b4ba")
        label_welcome = Label(
                window,
                text="Welcome Back To Our Trivia Game!",
                font=("Akaya Kanadaka",80,"bold"),
                bg = "#93b4ba")
        label_welcome.pack()

        label_enter_name = Label(
                window,
                text="Enter you name:",
                font=("Lato",50,"bold"),
                bg = "#93b4ba",
                fg="#3038d1")
        label_enter_name.pack(side=LEFT)


        entry_name = Entry(window,font=("Arial",40))
        entry_name.pack(side=LEFT)

        username_but = Button(
                window,
                text="Sumbit",
                font=("Jomhuria",10,"bold"),
                width=15,
                height=4,
                command=name,
                bg="#0f0f0f",
                fg="white")
        username_but.pack(side=LEFT)

        quit_but = Button(
                window,
                text="Quit",
                font=("Jomhuria",25,"bold"), 
                width=11,
                height=5,
                command=quit,
                bg="#b5aa72")
        quit_but.place(x=0,y=860)

        start_but = Button(
                window,
                text="Start",
                font=("Jomhuria",25,"bold"),
                width=11,
                height=5,
                command=trivia,
                bg="#a1ad90")
        start_but.place(relx = 1.0,rely = 1.0,anchor =SE)

        instructions_but = Button(
                window,
                text="Instructions",
                font=("Jomhuria",25,"bold"),
                width=11,
                height=5,
                command=instructions_Window,
                bg="#626363")
        instructions_but.pack(side=RIGHT)


def trivia():

        def End(correct_guesses):

                def play_again():
                        trivia()
                score_label = Label(
                        window,
                        text="You have answered " + str(correct_guesses) + " correct question",
                         font=("Playfair Display SC", 40, "bold"),
                        bg="#6378ff",
                        fg="#730505",
                        height=2)
                score_label.pack()

                score = int((correct_guesses/len(questions))*100)
                score_precent = Label(
                        window,
                        text="You score is " + str(score) + "%",
                        font=("Playfair Display SC", 45, "bold"),
                        bg="#6378ff",
                        fg="#52504d",
                        height=2)
                score_precent.pack()

                play_again_but = Button(
                        window,
                        text="Play Again",
                        bg="#28a663",
                        width=11,
                        height=5,
                        font=("Russo One", 25, "bold"),
                        command=play_again)
                play_again_but.place(relx = 1.0,rely = 1.0,anchor =SE)

                home_but = Button(
                        window,
                        text="Home",
                        bg="#7b22d4",
                        height=5,
                        width=11,
                        font=("Russo One", 25, "bold"),
                        command=Home)
                home_but.pack(side=BOTTOM)

                quit_but = Button(
                        window,
                        text="Quit",
                        font=("Jomhuria",25,"bold"),
                        width=11,
                        height=5,
                        command=quit,
                        bg="#b5aa72")
                quit_but.place(x=0,y=860)

                leaderboard[username] = score

                sorted_leaderboard = dict( sorted(leaderboard.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True))

                lead_lab = Label(
                        window,
                        text="Leaderboard: ",
                        font=("Arial",50,"bold"),
                        bg="#6378ff")
                lead_lab.place(x=0,y=400)
                y = 400

                for user in sorted_leaderboard:
                        leaderboard_label = Label(
                                window,
                                text="Username: "+str(user)+" "+"Score: "+str(sorted_leaderboard[user]),
                                font=("Arial",50,"bold"),
                                bg="#6378ff",
                                fg="#000000")
                        leaderboard_label.place(x=450,y=y)
                        y = y + 100

        def check_answer(answer, guess):

                if answer == guess:
                        return 1
                else:
                        return 0

        def clear():
                WaitState.set(1)
                for widgets in window.winfo_children():
                        widgets.destroy()

        def user_name():
                global username
                WaitSate_username.set(1)
                username = entry_username.get()
                for widgets in window.winfo_children():
                        widgets.destroy()
        
        def beginners():
                global questions
                global options
                WaitSate_difficulty.set(1)
                questions = questions_beg
                options = options_beg
                for widgets in window.winfo_children():
                        widgets.destroy()

        def professional():
                global questions
                global options
                WaitSate_difficulty.set(1)
                questions = questions_pro
                options = options_pro
                for widgets in window.winfo_children():
                        widgets.destroy()

        def clear_time():
                clear()


                time_up_label = Label(
                        window,
                        text="Time is up",
                        bg = "#6378ff",
                        fg="#000000",
                        font=("Arial", 100,"bold"))
                time_up_label.place(relx = 0.5,rely = 0.5,anchor = 'center')

                continue_but = Button(
                        window,
                        text="Continue",
                        font=("Knewave",25,"bold"),
                        bg="#942222",
                        width=11,
                        height=5,
                        command=clear)
                continue_but.place(relx = 1.0,rely = 1.0,anchor =SE)
                

                continue_but.wait_variable(WaitState)

                


        def button_countdown(i, label):
                if i > 0:
                        i -= 1
                        label.set(i)
                        window.after(1000, lambda: button_countdown(i, label))
                else:
                        clear_time()
                        


        window.config(bg="#6378ff")

        x = StringVar()
        WaitState = StringVar()
        WaitSate_username = StringVar()
        WaitSate_difficulty = StringVar()
        i = 0
        correct_guesses = 0

        count = 20
        button_label = StringVar()

        trophyImage = PhotoImage(file="trophy.png")
        redImage = PhotoImage(file="red.png")

        clear()


        label_enter_username = Label(
                window,
                text="Enter your username:",
                font=("Lato",50,"bold"),
                bg = "#6378ff",
                fg="#000000")
        label_enter_username.pack(side=LEFT)

        entry_username = Entry(
                window,
                font=("Arial",40))
        entry_username.pack(side=LEFT)

        username_but = Button(
                window,
                text="Continue",
                font=("Press Start 2P",10,"bold"),
                width=15,
                height=4,
                command=user_name,
                bg="#000000",
                fg="white")
        username_but.pack(side=LEFT)
        username_but.wait_variable(WaitSate_username)


        label_difficulty = Label(
                window,
                text="Choose your difficulty:",
                font=("Lato",100,"bold"),
                bg = "#6378ff",
                fg="#000000")
        label_difficulty.place(x=200,y=0)

        button_beg = Button(
                window,
                text="Beginner",
                font=("Press Start 2P",25,"bold"),
                width=25,
                height=10,
                command=beginners,
                bg="#bf0704",
                fg="white")
        button_beg.place(x=400,y=300)


        button_pro = Button(
                window,
                text="Professional",
                font=("Press Start 2P",25,"bold"),
                width=25,
                height=10,
                command=professional,
                bg="#bf0704",
                fg="white")
        button_pro.place(x=950,y=300)
        button_pro.wait_variable(WaitSate_difficulty)



        for key in questions:
                j = 0

                button_label.set(count)
                timer_label = Label(
                        window,
                        textvariable=button_label,
                        bg="#6378ff",
                        fg="#ff0000",
                        font=("Arial",46,"bold"))
                timer_label.pack()
                button_countdown(count, button_label)

                question_number = 0
                question_label = Label(
                        window,
                        text=key,
                        bg="#6378ff",
                        fg="#e8e8e8",
                        font=("Squada One",50,"bold"),
                        width=1920,
                        height=2)
                question_label.pack()

                continue_but = Button(
                        window,
                        text="Continue",
                        font=("Knewave",25,"bold"),
                        bg="#942222",
                        width=11,
                        height=5,
                        command=clear)
                continue_but.place(relx = 1.0,rely = 1.0,anchor =SE)

                quit_but = Button(
                        window,
                        text="Quit",
                        font=("Jomhuria",25,"bold"),
                        width=11,
                        height=5,
                        bg="#b5aa72",
                        command=window.destroy)
                quit_but.place(x=0,y=863)
                
                for index in options[question_number-1]:
                        options_radio = Radiobutton(
                                window,
                                text=options[i][j],
                                variable=x,
                                value=options[i][j],
                                bg="#6378ff",
                                font=("Squada One",30,"bold"),
                                fg="#000000",
                                height=3,
                                indicatoron=0,
                                activebackground="#209799",
                                width=1920)
                        options_radio.pack(anchor=W)

                        j += 1
                continue_but.wait_variable(WaitState)
                guess = x.get()
                guess = list(guess)
                for num in guess:
                       guess = num
                       break 
                correct_guesses = correct_guesses + check_answer(questions.get(key), guess)
                

                correct = check_answer(questions.get(key), guess)

                clear()
                if correct == 1:
                        correct_label = Label(window,
                                text="Correct!",
                                bg="#6378ff",
                                fg="#ffaa00",
                                font=("Arial",100,"bold"),
                                image = trophyImage,
                                compound='left')
                        correct_label.place(relx = 0.5,rely = 0.5,anchor = 'center')

                        continue_but = Button(
                                window,
                                text="Continue",
                                font=("Knewave",25,"bold"),
                                bg="#942222",
                                width=11,
                                height=5,
                                command=clear)
                        continue_but.place(relx = 1.0,rely = 1.0,anchor =SE)

                        continue_but.wait_variable(WaitState)
                elif correct == 0:
                        wrong_label = Label(
                                window,
                                text="Wrong!",
                                bg="#6378ff",
                                fg="#000000",
                                font=("Franklin Gothic Medium",100,"bold"),
                                image=redImage,
                                compound='left')
                        wrong_label.place(relx = 0.5,rely = 0.5,anchor = 'center')

                        continue_but = Button(
                                window,
                                text="Continue",
                                font=("Franklin Gothic Medium",25,"bold"),
                                bg="#942222",
                                width=11,
                                height=5,
                                command=clear)
                        continue_but.place(relx = 1.0,rely = 1.0,anchor =SE)

                        timer_label.destroy()

                        continue_but.wait_variable(WaitState)
                

                question_number = question_number + 1
                i += 1

        End(correct_guesses)


questions_pro = {
"How old is the universe?": "B",
"Who was the first person in space?": "C",
"How many bones does a human body have?": "A",
"What is the most populated country?": "A",
"What is the height of the tallest man in the world in 2021?": "D",
"What is the most valued company in the world?": "A",
"Who created python?": "B",
"How many oceans are there in the world?": "A",
"What is the distance between earth and mars?": "A",
"In which year the first windows version was released?": "D"
}


options_pro = [["A. 5.3 billion years old", "B. 13.8 billion years old", "C. 115.5 billion years ago", "D. 241.1 billion years old"],
          ["A. Alan Shepard", "B. Neil Armstrong", "C. Yuri Gagarin", "D. Buzz Aldrin"],
          ["A. 206", "B. 54", "C. 251", "D. 180"],
          ["A. China","B. Russia", "C. India", "D. United States"],
          ["A. 2.35 meters", "B. 2.47 meters","C. 2.71 meters", "D. 2.51 meters"],
          ["A. Apple", "B. Google", "C. Microsoft", "D. Amazon"],
          ["A. Brendan Eich", "B. Van Rossum", "C. Bjarne Stroustrups", "D. Dennis Ritchie"],
          ["A. Five", "B. Ten", "C. Seven", "D. Three"],
          ["A. 366.82 million km", "B. 251.87 milion km", "C. 1.578 milion km", "D. 350.34 milion km"],
          ["A. 1999", "B. 2001", "C. 1983", "D. 1985"]]


questions_beg = {
"In what years did the world war II took place?": "D",
"Who was the first presidnet of the U.S?": "B",
"In which year the first covid-19 case was discovered?": "C",
"How many continents are there in the world?": "A",
"How many planets are there in the solar system?": "D",
"What is the biggest technology company in South Korea?": "C",
"What was the first soft drink in space?": "B",
"Who holds the record for 100 metres dash?": "C",
"Which movie made the most money?": "A",
"How many states does the U.S is have?": "B"
}


options_beg = [["A. 1914-1921", "B. 1945-1948", "C. 1928-1935", "D. 1939-1945"],
          ["A. Abraham Lincoln", "B. George Washington", "C. John Tyler", "D. John Adams"],
          ["A. 2018", "B. 2001", "C. 2019", "D.2020"],
          ["A. Seven","B. Five", "C. Four", "D. Six"],
          ["A. Six", "B. Seven","C. Nine", "D. Eight"],
          ["A. Apple", "B. Xiaomi", "C. Samsung", "D. Huawei"],
          ["A. Water", "B. Coca Cola", "C. Fanta", "D. Pepsi"],
          ["A. Asafa Powell", "B. Yohan Blake", "C. Usain Bolt", "D. Tyson Gay"],
          ["A. Avatar", "B. Avengers: Endgame", "C. Titanic", "D. Star Wars: Episode VII"],
          ["A. 48", "B. 50", "C. 51", "D. 52"]]


leaderboard = {
        
}
        
window = Tk()
window.title("Home")
window.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
window.config(bg="#93b4ba")

Home()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please make a minimal working example of your problem? You have posted too much code for us to debug.

Comment: Also take a look at OOP

Comment: If you proceed to next slide before the end of current countdown task, you will create another countdown task.  So you need to *cancel* current countdown task using `.after_cancel(after_id)` where `after_id` is the ID returned by `.after()`.

Comment: what should the after_id contain?

Comment: @tamar Gayor. Your code is working. But I don't see timer overlapped.